# Python date string formatting

Tags: python, string, datetime

I want to remove the padded zeroes from a string-formatted python date:

```
formatted_date = my_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") # outputs something like: 01/01/2013
date_out = formatted_date.replace(r'/0', r'/').replace(r'^0', r'')
```

The second replace doesnt work-- I get 01/1/2013. How do I match the zero only if it's next to the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.replace()` does *not* take regular expressions. You are trying to replace the literal text `^0`.

Use `str.format()` to create a date format without zero-padding instead:

```
'{0.month}/{0.day}/{0.year}'.format(my_date)
```

and avoid having to replace the zeros.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> '{0.month}/{0.day}/{0.year}'.format(today)
'9/10/2013'
```

If Python was compiled with the `glibc` library, then you could also use dashes in the format to suppress the padding:

```
my_date.strftime('%-m/%-d/%y')
```

but that is not nearly as portable.

Comment: +1.  It would be nice though if `.strftime()` had versions of the format strings that allowed the omission of leading zeros.  Looks like this was [considered and rejected](http://bugs.python.org/issue14441).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: That'd be up to the C-API strftime() call. The standard doesn't have any such format parameter, C99 did add `%e` (*Day of the month, space-padded ( 1-31)*) but no equivalent for the month, and none without any padding.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Ah, thanks for that link, that gave me a new trick (limited to glibc platforms).

Comment: I didn't know the indices within the string could access object properties. Upvote for answering the question AND giving me a new tool for later.

Comment: how do you handle different cultures, where the format is DD/MM/YYYY vs MM/DD/YYYY ?

Comment: @NathanTregillus: use different formats? Better yet, use a localisation library like [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/) to handle date formatting for you.

Comment: i found the date.strftime method. i call it with the %x and it formats in the correct MM/DD/YYYY format